# Placement of the mudflap passes in the GCC compilation process

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am working on a project to build a bounds checking plugin for GCC. Since, this is similar in purpose to what *mudflap* does, it would be a good starting point. Hence, I began by trying to get the big picture as to why *mudflap* does the GIMPLE instrumentation in two passes and why are the passes placed at the locations they are. I understand that pass1 has to be performed on high GIMPLE and hence has to be earlier than the gimple lowering pass. However, I do not yet understand the rationale behind the placement of the second pass.
I'd appreciate it if some one can shed some light on this one. I've posted the same question on the gcc-help forum (here: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-02/msg00206.html), but there's no response yet. I am hoping someone here might be able to help.

Thanks!